# Changing the port that pure-ftpd uses

Tags: raspbian-jessie

So, I had a problem before I completed [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ftp.md), which was then fixed at the time (just a simple typo... not much) but now, another problem has shown up. This problem goes about the port that pure-ftpd listens to. My reason to change this port is that I have 2 different ftp servers running at my house and both of them use pure-ftpd, but what I want is that one of them listens to port 21 and the other to port 23. I've already searched in google on how to fix this problem, but when I tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1797116) forum post, the server wouldn't start up (would give an error when starting up, all because of the "Bind" script specified in those forums).

Both ftp servers are hosted under two different raspberry pi's 2 B 1gb ram models with debian jessie installed. Just to be clear, my question is: how do you change the port that pure-ftpd listens to?

Comment: Give this a try echo "<ip-address>,<port-number>" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind  using your IP address and port number. Then reboot.

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't work. It displays "Permission denied". Maybe I wrote something incorrectly when I created the Bind script manually?

Comment: try it with sudo

Comment: I tried with: sudo echo "0.0.0.0,23" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind ; But it didn't work, permission denied. Then I tried with: sudo echo "0.0.0.0,23" > sudo /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind ; But it doesn't display any output and doesn't create the Bind script, and finally I tried with: echo "0.0.0.0,23" > sudo /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind ; But it doesn't display any output again and doesn't create the Bind script either :/

Comment: so instead of echo why not create the file manually

Comment: That actually worked! I had already tried this with the forums I specified above, with their code over there, but the problem was that they placed spaces before and after the coma >.< the script worked as soon as I removed those spaces and wrote the script how you did it with the echo (no spaces)

Comment: Please do me a favor can you answer your own question, and let me know when you do so I can upvote it.

Comment: Done, answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve Robillard for letting me notice the problem.

The fix goes as to manually creating the script at "/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind" (just use: "sudo nano /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Bind") and writing this on it (change the "yourip" to your local ip or just leave it blank for all interfaces, and "port" to desired port).

```
<yourip>,<port>
```

As soon as you create the script, run the following command to restart the pure-ftpd server

```
sudo service pure-ftpd restart
```

IF you still get an error during startup, make sure that the script has NO SPACES. You can test if the server now is listening to the port you specified in the Bind script if you use

```
netstat -tunlp
```

and make sure that the port 21 is not being used now, but the port you specified in the Bind script.

Comment: I am going to delete most of our previous comments, so your answer really needs to stand on its own, so can you add the file that needs to be edited. You may also want to explain how to restart the ftp server.